# Best way to create a personal feed in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries

I'm building a social network app with the usual user-follower-relationship. My DynamoDB table is structured like this:

| Item | PK | SK | GSI1PK | GSI1SK | GSI2PK | GSI2SK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User: | USER#id | #META#id |  |  |  |  |
| Follow: | USER#id | FOLLOW#id | FOLLOW#id | USER#id |  |  |
| Post: | USER#id | POST#ulid | POST#ulid | #META#id | post[0-9] | POST#ulid |

I now want to create a feed for the user's front page.
The feed should include the 10 latests posts of the users the user is following.

My approach currently is to first query for all FOLLOWs of the user and then loop through all the user items and get their posts. But this approach could lead to a lot of read actions when the follower lists grow larger. Imagine a user having thousands of followed users.

Is there maybe a more efficient approach?

Comment: I think you would typically pre-compute each user's feed. When someone posts, that post is appended to each followers' feed.

Comment: Also may be of interest: [Twitter architecture](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html).